# How to change commit message after pushed to remote in Git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I added wrong commit message and pushed to server in Gitlab. Now I want to change commit message. Is it possible to change commit message after pushed to server?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> git commit --amend

When you run this command, it will ask you to change the commit message in a file. After changing it, make sure you push into the correct branch with the following command.

> git push -f origin "your branch"

Edit commit message without opening a file:

> git commit --amend -m "Your new commit message"

Comment: Be aware though that you're changing the history of a "public" (possibly already checked out by other users in their local working directory). You *must* therefore have explicit rights to do this. Even if you're the repository owner, you may have to perform some setup operation to turn this on.

Comment: @Obsidian: Agreed!